# How to install chrome (headless) in linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

I have an AWS EC2 running linux redhad. Is there a way to install the latest Chrome v59 on it so that I can run it in headless mode just like PhantomJS? All the resources I can find in google are about how to install it in ubuntu which has a UI. My Linux doesn't have a UI.

Thanks

Comment: This might help: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-yum-install-google-chrome-aws-linux-ami-konstantinos-demiris along with this: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=229187

Comment: Bearing in mind the `rpm --import` command and option may need to be run as root

Answer (score 5):

this question is kinda old, but someone may find the answer useful.

these commands install headless chrome in ubuntu:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
apt-transport-https \
ca-certificates \
curl \
gnupg \
hicolor-icon-theme \
libcanberra-gtk* \
libgl1-mesa-dri \
libgl1-mesa-glx \
libpango1.0-0 \
libpulse0 \
libv4l-0 \
fonts-symbola \
--no-install-recommends \
&& curl -sSL https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
&& echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list \
&& apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
google-chrome-stable \
--no-install-recommends \
&& apt-get purge --auto-remove -y curl \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

set -x \
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
ca-certificates \
curl \
unzip \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
&& curl -sSL "https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-talkplugin_current_amd64.deb" -o /tmp/google-talkplugin-amd64.deb \
&& dpkg -i /tmp/google-talkplugin-amd64.deb
ADD https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-talkplugin_current_amd64.deb /src/google-talkplugin_current_amd64.deb
```

hope this helps someone

Comment: This appears to install a non-headless version of Chrome, yes?

Comment: Right. Why do you need an icon theme in a contianer?

Comment: instructions provided are for Ubuntu but the requester asked for Linux i.e centos

Comment: why remove curl?

and then re-install it?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at projects like [chromeless](https://github.com/graphcool/chromeless) or [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) which both offer a feature-rich API as well as documentation on running on most hosting providers.

Alternatively, if you're looking for something custom-built for this then I run a SaaS called [browserless](https://browserless.io) that attacks the problem directly.

In any case, hope that helps

Comment: Puppeteer still downloads the browser in the background

Answer (score -16):

Follow these steps for install chrome in linux machine,

1. Download .rpm file from Chrome official website.
   [click here for download chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/) ,   download.rpm file.
2. Double click on .rpm file and install.

Comment: He said that his OS not have any GUI, so what double-click?